# How to write a query with group by in querydsl and spring boot jpa returning newest version of record?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, jpa, querydsl

My team and I have been stuck on this particular issue since a few weeks now and we can't figure out what we're missing. We're using angular with spring boot, java hibernate and a sql database. Currently we get data from one database which is connected to a crawler. Another database is in place for our application data.

Now... we have a table which should display only the very newest entries of the crawler database. An entry would look something like this:

```sql
id | type | number | version | ...
 
12   1      200      2015
```

The type and number indicate which record it involves. Meaning there can be another number **200** with the type **1** but with a newer version **2021**.

Currently we get all of the records per type with following query:

```java
// code
QRecord standard = QRecord.record;
BooleanBuilder query = new BooleanBuilder();

query.and(record.type.eq(type));
// code
```

We also tried it with a queryFactory:

```java
// code
queryFactory.selectFrom(record).where((record.type(type).collect(Collectors.toList()))
JPAExpressions.select(record.version.max()).from(record)))).fetch()
// code
```

Or those two mixed and compare the lists in the end:

```java
BooleanBuilder typeQuery = new BooleanBuilder();
typeQuery.and(record.type.eq(type).collect(Collectors.toList()))

List<Record> typeRecords = recordRepository.findAll(query, p).stream().map(x -> RecordMapper.mapRecord(x)).collect(Collectors.toList())

List<Record> newestRecords = queryFactory.selectFrom(record)
                         .where(record.version.eq(JPAExpressions.select(record.version.max())
                         .from(record))).fetch().stream().map(x -> RecordMapper.mapRecord(x))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

We thought maybe we need a **group by** but we didn't make any progress regarding that.
We couldn't find a solution where we get no duplicate data and only the newest versions. Please help.

I can provide more information and code if necessary.

Comment: have you tried something like sorting by version 'desc' and using 'limit 1' ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to eliminate al id's for which a higher version number exists:

```
SELECT a
LEFT JOIN b.id ON a.id = b.id and a.version < b.version
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```